# Tangent planes of a convex surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Is it true that a convex surface of class $C^1$ cannot have three parallel tangent planes?
If it is true, where can one find a proof?

Comment: Do you know that a convex surface must be entirely on one side of each tangent plane?

Comment: What about a smooth convex body whose boundary contains a flat region?

Comment: @Didier That is not the usual use of the term in geometry. Wouldn’t that be called weakly convex or something else?

Comment: @TedShifrin I (and other people) use convex / strictly convex if the second fundamental form is positive semi-definite / definite. I don't think it is unusual.